# How to grab text from vscode snippet prefix and use it in body?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to grab a part from snippet prefix and use it in body of vscode snippet.

For example, If I type `self:name`, it'll converted to `self.__name = name`

How to grab the text `name` as a variable and use in it snippet body?

Comment: use `Hypersnips` because build in snippets don't allow regex prefix definition

Comment: How can I do this in `HyperSnips`??